# Update record based on datetime field in sqlite

Tags: sqlite, cordova

I am using sqlite with phonegap and i want to update data where datetime field has same value.

## TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE "MyTable" 
(
"VehicleNumber" TEXT, "VehicleImage" TEXT, "LocationId" INTEGER, "LocationName" TEXT, "StartTime" DATETIME, "EndTime" DATETIME, "ComputedCharge" DOUBLE, "InsertedDateTime" DATETIME, "InsertedBy" INTEGER, "UpdatedDateTime" DATETIME, "UpdatedBy" INTEGER, "PaymentIncash" BOOL, "EntryUpdateOnServer" BOOL, "ExitUpdateOnServer" BOOL
)
```

## DATA

```
INSERT INTO "MyTable" VALUES ("ERA 75TM","Pictures/ERA 75TM.jpeg","1","surat","2014-08-05 13:5:35","2014-08-05 15:40:48","17","2014-08-05 13:5:35","3","2014-08-05 15:40:48","3","false","false","false");
```

## UPDATE QUERY NOT WORKS

```
UPDATE MyTable SET 
    VehicleImage='Pictures/ERA 75TM.jpeg',
    ComputedCharge=17,
    EntryUpdateOnServer='true',
    ExitUpdateOnServer='true' 
WHERE VehicleNumber='ERA 75TM' AND StartTime=DATETIME('2014-08-05 13:05:35') AND LocationId=1
```

Comment: means record not update even record is exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
"2014-08-05 13:5:35"
               ^
```

A string with a single-digit minute value is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), and is not the string that you're searching for.

Comment: yes you are right now it's work fine and i can update record based on datetime field is matched with passed datetime :). Thanks dude..

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully the following suits your purpose.

Using "true" or "false" for BOOL doesn't work. BOOL is really an integer underneath, not a string. You are therefore use true or false, or simply 1 or 0.

DATETIME(string) does not work. Not sure if this is supposed to work like that because the string can be in any number of formats. Anyway, I used STR_TO_DATE and it works as expected.

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
  `VehicleNumber` TEXT,
  `VehicleImage` TEXT, 
  `LocationId` INTEGER, 
  `LocationName` TEXT, 
  `StartTime` DATETIME, 
  `EndTime` DATETIME, 
  `ComputedCharge` DOUBLE, 
  `InsertedDateTime` DATETIME, 
  `InsertedBy` INTEGER, 
  `UpdatedDateTime` DATETIME, 
  `UpdatedBy` INTEGER, 
  `PaymentIncash` BOOL, 
  `EntryUpdateOnServer` BOOL, 
  `ExitUpdateOnServer` BOOL
);

INSERT INTO `MyTable` VALUES ("ERA 75TM","Pictures/ERA 75TM.jpeg","1","surat","2014-08-05 13:5:35","2014-08-05 15:40:48","17","2014-08-05 13:5:35","3","2014-08-05 15:40:48","3",false,false,false);

UPDATE `MyTable` SET 
    VehicleImage='Pictures/ERA 75TM.jpeg',
    ComputedCharge=17,
    EntryUpdateOnServer=false,
    ExitUpdateOnServer=false 
WHERE VehicleNumber='ERA 75TM' AND StartTime=STR_TO_DATE('2014-08-05 13:05:35','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') AND LocationId=1;
```

Comment: SQLite has no `STR_TO_DATE`, or a `false` literal.

Comment: Oh, okay. I was using SQL. I guess you have figure out sqlite equivalent.